# How can I convert a cell like "12/04/2003" into date format?

Tags: microsoft-excel

21/03/2004 doesn't register as a date, while 7/3/2004 does register as a date. Does anyone know how I could remove all the 0s in values of dates with month values starting at 0?

So the columns that are glued to the left margin somehow don't get autoconverted. the columns glued to the right are fine.

[image: http://puu.sh/27CEm]

Comment: Just format the column as dd/m/yy

Comment: Oh - I just tried formatting it in the UK date format and somehow it still doesn't work. Hmm..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally, this could be solved by using the DATEVALUE function to convert a date that is text to an Excel date value (i.e., a number that Excel will recognize as date). The usage would be DATEVALUE(date_string or cell_address).

However, this will not work here because 1) Day precedes Month in your example strings and DATEVALUE expects Month followed by Day, and 2) for some of the date strings a time is also included.

Here is an array formula alternative that works with the examples you provided. It would need to be entered using the <kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Enter</kbd> key combination.

```
  =DATE(
        RIGHT(IFERROR(LEFT(F8,IFERROR(SEARCH(" ",F8),0)-1),F8),MATCH("/",MID(IFERROR(LEFT(F8,IFERROR(SEARCH(" ",F8),0)-1),F8),LEN(IFERROR(LEFT(F8,IFERROR(SEARCH(" ",F8),0)-1),F8))-ROW(1:25),1),0)),

        LEFT(IFERROR(LEFT(F8,IFERROR(SEARCH(" ",F8),0)-1),F8),SEARCH("/",IFERROR(LEFT(F8,IFERROR(SEARCH(" ",F8),0)-1),F8))-1),

        LEN(IFERROR(LEFT(F8,IFERROR(SEARCH(" ",F8),0)-1),F8))-MATCH("/",MID(IFERROR(LEFT(F8,IFERROR(SEARCH(" ",F8),0)-1),F8),LEN(IFERROR(LEFT(F8,IFERROR(SEARCH(" ",F8),0)-1),F8))-ROW(1:25),1),0)-LEN(LEFT(IFERROR(LEFT(F8,IFERROR(SEARCH(" ",F8),0)-1),F8),SEARCH("/",IFERROR(LEFT(F8,IFERROR(SEARCH(" ",F8),0)-1),F8))+1)))
        )
```

This very complicated array formula (I hope someone can offer a simpler one) uses the DATE function to construct an Excel date value. (I happened to have the original date string in cell F8 when I built the date.)

The date string that needs to be converted cannot be used in its raw form because it sometimes includes a time. What is used instead is `RIGHT(IFERROR(LEFT(F8,IFERROR(SEARCH(" ",F8),0)-1),F8)`. This formula searches for a space in the date string. If it finds a space, it uses the LEFT function to get all the characters to the left of the space; if it doesn't find a space, it simply returns the original string.

The outermost part of the formula is the DATE function: When given the Year, Month, and Day, it yields an Excel date. I've broken out the calculation of these three pieces in the code above.

The Year calculation is as follows:

1. Reverse the date string (with the time clipped off as explained above).
2. Find the position of the first "/" in this reversed string using the SEARCH function (This slash is actually the first slash in the unreversed date string.)
3. Take that many characters from the right of the date string with the RIGHT function.

The Month calculation has the steps:

1. Find the position of the first slash in the *unreversed* date string.
2. Determine the number of characters in the month (which could be 1 or 2) by calculating the difference between this position and the position of the second "/" as determined in the Year calculation.
3. Use the MID function to return the characters between the first slash and the second slash.

The Day calculation is the simplest.

1. Calculate the position of the first "/" using the same method as in the Month calculation.
2. Take that many characters (minus 1) from the left-hand side of the string using the LEFT function .

There are less elaborate ways to get the result, the simplest of which would undoubtedly be the use of the Text to Columns command on the Data tab of the Ribbon, as suggested by @Barry.

Another way to proceed is using a REGEX pattern-matching function. This function is not built into Excel, but can be constructed and accessed with VBA code. Though the code is a little tricky, several version are available on the net (such as [this example](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/818802)). However, using the function would be very simple. For example, the match expression for getting the Day might be something like `REGEXP("./",F8)`, which could then be used in the DATE function to get the Excel date value.

For convenience, here is the formula in its complete form.

```
  =DATE(RIGHT(IFERROR(LEFT(F8,IFERROR(SEARCH(" ",F8),0)-1),F8),MATCH("/",MID(IFERROR(LEFT(F8,IFERROR(SEARCH(" ",F8),0)-1),F8),LEN(IFERROR(LEFT(F8,IFERROR(SEARCH(" ",F8),0)-1),F8))-ROW(1:25),1),0)),LEFT(IFERROR(LEFT(F8,IFERROR(SEARCH(" ",F8),0)-1),F8),SEARCH("/",IFERROR(LEFT(F8,IFERROR(SEARCH(" ",F8),0)-1),F8))-1),MID(IFERROR(LEFT(F8,IFERROR(SEARCH(" ",F8),0)-1),F8),LEN(LEFT(IFERROR(LEFT(F8,IFERROR(SEARCH(" ",F8),0)-1),F8),SEARCH("/",IFERROR(LEFT(F8,IFERROR(SEARCH(" ",F8),0)-1),F8))+1)),LEN(IFERROR(LEFT(F8,IFERROR(SEARCH(" ",F8),0)-1),F8))-MATCH("/",MID(IFERROR(LEFT(F8,IFERROR(SEARCH(" ",F8),0)-1),F8),LEN(IFERROR(LEFT(F8,IFERROR(SEARCH(" ",F8),0)-1),F8))-ROW(1:25),1),0)-LEN(LEFT(IFERROR(LEFT(F8,IFERROR(SEARCH(" ",F8),0)-1),F8),SEARCH("/",IFERROR(LEFT(F8,IFERROR(SEARCH(" ",F8),0)-1),F8))+1))))
```

Comment: Hmm - I tried that, but it outputs #VALUE! for some weird reason.

Comment: IquilineKea, I didn't read the question closely enough. You're almost certainly getting the error because DATEVALUE expects mm/dd/yy. More brute force approach may be required. Will amend my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The value that glues to the left side generally means that it's a textual value, whereas numeric/date value is aligned to the right.

Perhaps you can also check out these things before making a possible date time conversion in Excel:

1. Check your system Language/Region settings, especially your date time format. Excel uses your default system date time settings, and date time conversion will be different for different regions as a result.
2. Make sure there's no extra white-spaces or hidden line break character attached to your cell value, a valid date time value with a white-space will be treated as the text value, not the date time, thus Excel will not auto-convert it.
3. Use Excel's custom cell format option, where you can specify your own conversion rules, such as DD/MM/YYYY.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably the source format is dd/mm/yyyy. Try using "Text to columns" functionality to convert.

Select column of dates

Data > Text to Columns > Next > Next > under "column data format" select "date" and choose the source format from the dropdown - "DMY" > OK

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I just tried that but it still got a similar error. =/ I just found my own solution to the problem though - although it involves artificially changing my Windows calendar settings to dd/mm/yyyy.

Comment: What error do you get - an actual error or wrong dates?

Answer (score 0):

I saw that you just found a solution, but if this works it should be a simpler workaround.

Select the cells that are not formatted as dates. Right click, select format cells, choose Numbers and category Custom. There set a format that is the input format in the type field, you type it in by hand because there will be no format that will suit you. In you case input the string dd/mm/yyyy, press OK. Now excel knows this is a date (although with the format day month year), you can copy and paste this cell into a new cell that is formatted as a date the way you want it.

Answer (score 0):

The default data format in Excel is :dd/m/yyyy. The left margin don't get autoconverted becuase you choose: m/dd/yyyy. Just choose the right format will solve your problem.